# Dictionary groupby visitdate and IsChecked property C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, group-by

I have  a dictionary of SelectNode class in SelectList class:

```
public Dictionary<long, SelectNode> Tbl;
```

SelectNode has the following properties:

```
        public long SectionId;
        public int State;
        public string Project;
        public string Name;
        public string VisitDate;
        public long Run;
        public SectionMsg Msg;
        public bool Checked;
```

in SelectList class , I want to create  dictionary grouped by VisitDate which only have Checked property =true

this is the method I have :

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Method filters checkeditems from SelectNode class via SelectList class
    /// </summary>
    public void GetSelected()
    {
        foreach (SelectNode sn in this.Buf.Lst.Selected)
        {
           //Dont know what to put here to generate new dicationary
        }
    }
```

long SecdtionId is the key in dictionary. Thank you in advance.

Comment: these fields are in the private class within public class

Comment: there is private class DataRec within public class SelectNode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following LINQ statement should do it, assuming that `string` in `VisitDate` is parseable.

```
var ordered = this.Buf.Lst.Selected.Where(o=> o.Value.Checked).GroupBy(o => DateTime.Parse(o.Value.VisitDate));
```

or if you want to order them as `strings` then just

```
  var ordered = Tbl.Where(o=> o.Value.Checked).GroupBy(o => o.Value.VisitDate);
```

You need to add `using System.Linq;` to your `using` statement list.

Comment: this.Buf.Lst.Selected  = object which returns the instance of SelectList and does not have orderby method

Comment: You need to add `using System.Linq;` at the top of the `.cs` file, you are trying to `foreach` over that object so it must be `IEnumerable` which allows to use `LINQ`

Comment: Thank you LIUFA, var ordered = this.Buf.Lst.Selected.Where(o => o.Checked).GroupBy(o => o.VisitDate); works fine

Comment: how do I convert var ordered to dictionary or list?

Comment: Basically in SelectList class I want to have the dictionary on top and then in this method convert the ordered to CheckedDictionary or something like that

Comment: @FaisalShah `var` does not work like that, it infers type from the left side of equation, it 'becomes' whatever type is returned.

Comment: so what approach I should take? Should I make another class with properties and loop through dictionary and add each element , but then how would I create the grouping that way?